# Why deploy a .p12 client certificate bundled with a root CA?

Tags: certificates

I have been asked to connect to a government agency secure site
that uses client certificates to authenticate its clients.
I received by email an encrypted client certificate as a PKCS#12 file
and by other means the password for the file.

The interesting fact is that the PKCS12 file *also contains
a root certificate authority* for that government agency ; when you 
install the certificate in Firefox, it will also trust the associated root CA.
When you install on Windows it will prompt for install and trust the 
associated root CA.

The government site uses TLS with a certificate generated by that particular root CA,
so I think this is the reason why it was bundled in the first place.

But.. from the client point of view, trusting this new root CA is a real security issue.

I guess this site could have been created in a different manner that would not involve
planting a new root CA in its clients (i.e. [Use Client Certificate using Self Signed CA while using Web Certificate of a publicly trusted CA](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36069/use-client-certificate-using-self-signed-ca-while-using-web-certificate-of-a-pub))

Is this government agency trying to be malicious with its root CA, **or is it just a cost-effective, acceptable solution ?**

*nb: There is good documentation for TLS around the web, but not about client certificates deployment. I could not easily find good documented best practices for deploying such a "platform" using client certificate authentication.*

Comment: So what is your goal? If you do not want to install the ca, you can ignore it, just install the client certificate, that will not effect the tls handshake, just give you a warning that the server is not trusted. -----------------------------------
You may be able to get answer from here:
[In cryptography, PKCS #12 defines an archive file format for ***storing many cryptography objects as a single file***. It is commonly used to bundle a private key with its X.509 certificate or to ***bundle all the members of a chain of trust***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12)

Comment: I want to know if this is an "acceptable" way of setting up a securized site. If this is a good practice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the p12 contents are determined by the tool used to create them. Government agencies are almost legendary in their odd choices of tools and software. It's quite unlikely that anyone involved has thought this through as thoroughly as you have.

Comment: So, you mean this is an odd choice ? Not exactly a good thing ?

Comment: I mean it's a default choice and no intent should be read in to it.